# Preserving scope across routed views

Tags: angularjs

I have a SPA with a list of Clients displayed on the landing page.  Each client has an edit button, which if clicked should take me to an Edit view for that selected Client.

I'm not sure how to go about this- all the routes I've seen so far will just take my client id in the $routeParams, and then most examples will then pull the Client from a factory by that Id.

But I already HAVE my Client... seems a waste to hit my web api site again when I already have it.  Is it possible to route to the new view and maintain the selected Client in the $scope?
Edit:
This is what I did- I don't know if it's better or worse than Clarks response... I just made the following angular service:

```
app.service('clientService', function () {
    var client = null;

    this.getClient = function () {
        return client;
    };

    this.setClient = function (selectedClient) {
        client = selectedClient;
    };
});
```

And then for any controller that needs that data:

```
$scope.client = clientService.getClient();
```

This seemed to work fine... but would love to hear how this is good or bad.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding routes in angular, they are just client side, this isn't causing a round trip to your server it's just watching the url in the browser, when that changes (using the hash to avoid changing locations actually) angular parses it and loads a template and controller and passes along any parameters in the routeParams to the new controller.

Comment: That part I get- but the controller, which had my previous $scope with the selected client is now gone.  I think I need to use a service to keep track of selection state as it is a singleton.

Comment: Yeah that's basically how I'm handling it threw together a fiddle to show the route config stuff itself: http://jsfiddle.net/mU266/ Basically how I'm handling this is I have a service that makes a call to the server and stores the data, then I use the routeParams to pass an ID from one controller to another, the service I wrote has a method to look up the objects by id.

Comment: The only bit of added complexity I don't like about doing it this way is I need to have a $watch in the controllers that deals with doing this if the person is coming directly to the page and therefore the service hasn't yet loaded the data.  It's not a huge deal but adds a bit of code I'd rather not have to deal with.  Here's an updated fiddle with the params working too http://jsfiddle.net/mU266/2/

Comment: Hmm, so the angularjs service itself is a singleton and will preserve state across controllers... so in my case I can store the selected client and then grab it when I get to my edit view.  All client side.  Problem seems to be more how to tell the angularjs service to set the selected client to null when navigating away from the edit page...

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what level of caching you want.

You could depend on browser caching, in which case proper HTTP headers will suffice.

You could depend on cache provided by $http in angular, in which case making sure the parameters you send up are the same would be sufficient.

You could also create your own model caching along the lines of :

```
module.factory('ClientModel', function($http, $cacheFactory, $q){
    var cache = $cacheFactory('ClientModel');
    return {
        get : function(id){
            var data = cache.get(id);
            if(data){
                //Using $q.when to keep the method asynchronous even if data is coming from cache
                return $q.when(data);
            } else {
                //Your service logic here:
                var promise = $http.get('/foo/bar', params).then(function(response){
                    //Your model logic here
                    var data = response;
                    cache.put(id, data);
                    return response;
                }, function(response){
                    cache.remove(id);
                    return response;
                });
                //Store the promise so multiple concurrent calls will only make 1 http request
                cache.put(id, promise);
                return promise;
            }
        },
        clear : function(id){
            if(angular.isDefined(id)){
                cache.remove(id);
            } else {
                cache.removeAll();
            }
        }
    }
});

module.controller('ControllerA', function(ClientModel){
    ClientModel.get(1).then(function(){
        //Do what you want here
    });
});

module.controller('ControllerB', function(ClientModel){
    ClientModel.get(1).then(function(){
        //Do what you want here
    });
});
```

Which would mean each time you request a client object with the same 'id', you would get the same object back.

Comment: This makes a ton of sense @Clark Pan, thanks for writing this up, I'll very likely fix my services to use promises as you show here.  Also wasn't aware of the cacheFactory will have to read up on that.

Comment: Thanks @shaunhusain. I've only recently decided on this model after some experimentation.

Comment: @ClarkPan I like your approach- I added some code to my question on what I currently have working... pros and cons to my approach?  Just trying to learn...

Comment: It depends. With the style of service you've written, it would need to depend on each controller to correctly take and store the request in the service, meaning the logic for your model is possibly duplicated across a bunch of controllers.